# Return multiple relationships as one in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Consider a query where to get from node A to node D you must travel through a couple of relationships, ex.

```
(:Person)-[:LIVES_IN]->(:State)-[:HAS]->(:Parks)
```

and I wanted to return on the fly all the possible Parks a Person can go to in their State, without returning the State itself in the query such that the returned relationship looks like

```
(:Person)-->(:Parks)
```

In other words so that:

[image]

What would the query look like?

**Thank you for your time!**

Answer (score 3):

You could use APOC to return a virtual relationship something like this...

```
MATCH (person:Person {name: 'Dave'})-[:LIVES_IN|HAS*]->(park:Park)
WITH person, park
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(person,'CAN_VISIT',{}, park) YIELD rel
RETURN person, park, rel
```

Comment: Thanks Dave! Thats actually very close to what I'm looking for, I just have to tweak a few things.

Comment: I'm new so I upvoted but it doesn't show, but I dont know how to select yours as the correct one

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get all the Parks a Person can go to you can simply query for:

```
MATCH (:Person)-[*]->(p:Parks)
RETURN p
```

Comment: The problem is that for my purposes I need the path, so when I do p=(query) return p the result is everything between A and D. And that is why I'm trying to reduce the path to one relationship.

Comment: But if you need the path the result should be everything, since you have not direct relations between (:Person) and (:Park). You should define some constraints then.

Comment: H. Trujillo, maybe is a good idea edit your post and add a more complete example. Maybe a graph a bit more close to your real problem (Person, Parks and State) and what result you wish get with a Cypher Query.

Comment: @DaveBennett's answer was actually very close to what I needed, but thanks for your time!

Comment: @H.Trujillo you can store the path in a variable when matching like this MATCH path=(:Person)-[*]->(park:Parks) RETURN park, path;   Just note that this will give you all possible paths. If you want just one path you will need to filter somehow (like use the shortestpath function)